# How move the biggest file in each subdirectory to current directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, mv

I like to loop though subdirectories and move the biggest file to its parent and then delete the folder. I have tried many things but never got it working correctly.

It says that `mv` cant find the file or folder on this one.

```
dir[123]/something.mkv
dir[123]/something-small.txt
dir[555]/otherthing.mkv
dir[555]/otherthing-small.txt
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in */ ; do
    FIND=$(find . -type f -exec ls -al {} \; | sort -nr -k5 | head -n 1)
    echo "$d${FIND##*/}"
    mv "$d${FIND##*/}" .
done
```

Comment: Hmmm... why not use `ls -1 --sort=size dir| head -1` for finding the biggest file in a dir? Then it's just a matter of looping through them... but be careful, size and length of a file are not always the same thing. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @Rmano because that will break if the file names contain spaces, tabs, newlines, shell glob characters or backslashes. `find` is a much better approach.

Comment: @terdon They're using `ls` into the loop too --- doubt it will work with spaces. `"$(ls -1 --sort=size dir| head -1)"` will work with spaces and tabs and similar, and if they have newlines in filenames, then they deserve it :-P

Comment: @Rmano (scratch the last version if you saw it), yes, you're quite right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is failing because you are searching in the current directory and not the target. Change your find to:

```
find "$d" -type f -exec ls -al {} \; | sort -nr -k5 | head -n 1
```

However, a safer way would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in */ ; do
    file=$(find "$d" -type f -printf "%s\t%f\n" | sort -n | tail -n 1 | cut -f 2- )
    echo "$file"
    mv "$d${file}" .
done
```

While this will still break if your file names contain newlines, at least it will work with file names containing spaces.

---

If your files can also contain newlines, you can try this instead:

```
#!/bin/bash
for d in */ ; do
    max=0
    file=""
    for f in "$d"/*
    do
        ## If this is a file and its size is greater than the max so far,
        ## save it as "$file" and uts size as "$max".
        [[ -f "$f" ]] && [[ $(stat -c "%s" "$f") -gt $max ]] && max="$size" && file="$f"
    done
    ## move the largest file. Use "mv -i" to be prompted before overwriting. 
    mv "$file" .
done
```

Comment: Newlines in filenames, do you mean if the find output would break into a new line or can we have actual newline characters in filenames?

Comment: @redanimalwar the latter. Try `touch foo$'\n'bar`. The only characters not allowed in file names are `/` and `\0`.

Comment: Thanks, did not know this but I do not care, I see no value in having newlines in filenames and never came across any file that had this, well at least not that I know of.

Comment: @redanimalwar of course not, I doubt anyone would create one on purpose. On the other hand, you should never underestimate the ability of random users to screw up a system and it is good practice to always make your scripts robust and capable of dealing with all possible file names.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
find "$d" -type f ...
```

instead of

```
find . -type f ...
```

`.` is your current folder and you mean the elements provided by `$d`.